# Xdebug won't connect to VS Code on Windows 10 with XAMPP dev server

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I think I've read through every Xdebug not working question but I cannot seem to get Xdebug to connect to VS Code.

I'm serving a Laravel application on a fresh install of XAMPP PHP 7.2 for Win32. I overwrote the `public/index.php` file to just:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */
phpinfo();
```

... with a breakpoint set on the last line with `phpinfo()`.

Here is my **VSCode launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed the Apache server root also but I don't know if that makes a difference (`httpd.conf`):

```
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/simple-budget/public"
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/simple-budget/public">
```

And finally the tail end of my `php.ini` (nothing else altered except for enabled pgsql extension) file configuration (copied from multiple issues similar to this one to no avail):

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = "D:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll"
xdebug.remote_enabled=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

What am I missing here? I've restarted Apache a million times to make sure. Added the debug extension to Firefox even though autostart is enabled.

Edit:

Xdebug does show up in my phpinfo() page.

```
Version     2.6.0
IDE Key     colesam
Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

I don't know why the IDE key is colesam but none of the solutions I found for VS Code had to do with the IDE key.

Comment: Xdebug shows up in `phpinfo()`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does (see edit).

Comment: 1) Please provide whole Xdebug section of phpinfo output; 2) What Xdebug log has to say about it?

Comment: I replaced the image with the full xdebug section. I do not know where the log is located but that section says that xdebug.log is set to none.

Answer (score 1):

I had also problem to connect **VS code** and **XDebug** ( PHP / XAMPP ) , trying everything ( PHP.INI settings, launch.json, admin rights, firewall ). At the end I have added PHP installation directory to the windows *Path* variable. From this moment, everything works fine ...

Not sure if this is exactly the case, but can be one of the reasons.

Comment: This is helpful but may be better suited as a comment, or at least direct information on what directory you added and to where specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for the record, it looks like you have `xdebug.remote_enabled=1` in your config, it should be `xdebug.remote_enable=1`.

This is born out by your phpinfo output:
`xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off`

However, your post helped me get over my hump, I had `remote_autostart` off (default value in fresh install on Fedora 33 from remi repo), turning that on got my VSCode debugger connection working :)